# Using the null coalescing operator inside a higher order function

Tags: c#, lambda, functional-programming, closures, higher-order-functions

I am trying to wrap my head around whether this is possible. My hunch is that it is not but wanted to confirm.

The following higher order function uses the null coalescing operator:

```
    public static Func<T> Coalesce<T>(this Func<T> source)
        where T : class
    {
        T local = default(T); 
        return delegate
        {
            return local ?? (local = source()); 
        }; 
    }
```

The goal is to use it inside a property like so:

```
    protected string SomeMember
    {
        get { return Coalesce(() => GetSomeMember())(); }
    }
```

If it worked as intended, the GetSomeMember() function would only be called once the first time the property is called. Thereafter the stored instance of the property can be returned. (its basic memoization / null coalescing concept).

Now the tricky part comes in trying to trap the stored instance inside a closure instead of opting to use a private field. I know you could store the state of 'SomeMember' inside the class which contains SomeMember, but I am explicitly trying to avoid that just for curiosity's sake. The goal would be for everything needed to remain inside the get { } block (that includes **not** storing the delegate returned from Coalesce()).

Since both the inner returned function and the outer function are called everytime the property is accessed, there is a problem. The 'T local' variable gets re-assigned every time, and thus the null coalescing operator always re-invokes GetSomeMember().

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you not just trying to encapsulate a lazy instantiation?

Comment: No, the point is for what would normally be a private field, to instead to be a closed over variable.

Comment: @SeanThoman, closure is always associated with some delegate (or `Expression`). And if you want to create the closure once and then repeatedly use it, it means you need to store the delegate somewhere, probably in a field.

Comment: @Svick, you are right. I guess its possible if you somehow stored that delegate outside the class, but maybe not a great option. Anyway that answers the question.

Comment: @Sean It turns out that you are indeed wanting some form of [Lazy Load](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) or lazy instantiation. [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is a much more complex requirement. If you just wanted a [closed over variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)), you would simply use C# automatic properties with a private setter. What you have there in [svick's answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9833217/56145) is lazy instantiation. Hence the `Lazy` type.

Comment: @cottsak, Its actually a bit more than just lazy instantiation, althought lazy instantiation is part of it. The point is that the public property should be the only access point for the lazy loading functionality. In the case of using a private field and a public property, there are two access points from within the class, and furthermore m_someMember could be re-assigned. However, I do think I could try using a public readonly Lazy<T> and assign it within the constructor -- that would essentially do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't work like this, because you're calling `Coalesce()` (not a great name, BTW) every time you call the getter. You could save the delegate to a field and use that. But if you're doing that, it's much better to use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) from the framework:

```
private Lazy<string> m_someMember = new Lazy<string>(GetSomeMember);

protected string SomeMember
{
    get { return m_someMember.Value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not look possible since whatever closure you will try to get inside getter will not be able to survive past that call (as you don't want to store anything on the object).